# Prove $S^1$ is a differentiable manifold; does this proof work?

Tags: proof-writing, solution-verification, manifolds

This is along the lines of proof verification. We covered this example in class and I want to make sure I have understood it as geometry is not something I'm particularly good at.

By $S^1$ I mean the unit circle embedded in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

To show $S^1$ is a differentiable manifold, we are required to verify the following: That there are (possibly infinitely many) charts at each point covering $M$ such that the change of coordinates over overlapping maps is continuous in the usual sense.

We define 4 charts $U_u, U_d, U_l, U_r$ corresponding to the open upper, lower, left, and right half circles. i.e. the half circles corresponding to $y>0, y<0, x<0, x>0$ respectively. It is easy enough to see that these open subsets of $S^1$ will cover $S^1$. On $U_u$ and $U_d$ we define $x_{u,d}:S^1\to(-1,1)$ to be the map $(x,y)\mapsto(x)$. It is easy to verify this map is 1-1 homeomorphism. Similarly, on $U_l$ and $U_r$ we define $x_{l,r}:S^1\to(-1,1)$ to be the map $(x,y)\mapsto y$.

It suffices to show that on the overlaps between these, that the coordinate change transition is $C^1$. First, we consider the overlap between $U_u$ and $U_l$. i.e. the open upper-left quarter circle. We the inverse map of $x_u$ is the map $x_{u}^{-1}:\mathbb{R}\to S^1$ such that $x\mapsto\sqrt{1-x^2}$. Composing this with $x_l$, we have $x_1\circ x_u^{-1}=\sqrt{1-x^2}$, which is indeed $C^1$. We can similarly deal with the other overlaps.

Is this all there is to this proof/example? Also, I have worked primarily in mathematical logic before this, so I want to verify that my proof-writing technique for this sort of thing is coherent. Also, I believe what I refer to as a coordinate transition map is the property of chart compatibility?

Comment: Careful language. $u_{u,d}$ is a map on $S^1,$ so it is wrong to say it is a homeomorphism. The restrictions to $U_d$ and $U_u$ are both homeomorphisms.

Comment: The traditional approach is to use two charts, on $V_r=S^1\setminus\{(-1,0)\}$ and $V_l=S^1\setminus\{(1,0)\}.$ Then $f_r:(-\pi,\pi)\mapsto V_r$ is defined as $t\mapsto (\cos t,\sin  t)$ and $f_l:(-\pi,\pi)\to V_l$ with $t\mapsto (-\cos t,-\sin t).$ $V_l\cap V_r$ corresponds to $T=(-\pi,\pi)\setminus\{0\}$ in both primates, and $$f_l^{-1}(f_r(t))=\begin{cases}t+\pi&t<0\\t-\pi&t>0\end{cases}$$

Comment: But your proof works, and is fine here. There really isn’t much more to it in this simple example.

Comment: The reason the traditional approach is preferred is that it generalizes. If $G$ is a discrete subgroup of $(\mathbb R^m,+)$ and $f:\mathbb R^m\to \mathbb R^n$ is differentiable and satisfies $f(x)=f(y)$ iff $x-y\in G,$ then $f(\mathbb R^m)$ can be made a differentiable manifold using for charts $f(U)$ where we restrict to open $U\subset \mathbb R^m$  such that for $x,y\in U,$ $x-y\notin G.$

Comment: (Ignore the word ‘primates’ in my previous comment. Not sure what I wrote that gave me that word. Posting from iPad has some risks.)